# Wordpress as blogengine documentation

Tags: wordpress

I want to use wordpress as an weblog engine for my office. the people could be able to register and select their theme, like wordpress.com . but i don't know how can i configure it to be a blog engine not just an alone weblog.

Would you guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is build a multisite WordPress installation.  Here's the official WordPress site for that http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network